# Parse Backbone object fetch

Tags: backbone.js

I have collection of ticket objects .The ticket object have property company, customer, service address which are in different table. Currently am using nested api calls for getting all the information . Is there anyway to do it in single step like query property of Collection

Current impl:

1. Fetch all the tickets:

   iterate through the list and for each ticket fetch cmpny customer and service address.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is under the backend responsibility to do the job. Your current implementation uses [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), where you want to have a eager loading.
So you can add a query parameter and return a full Json tree, with all needed data.

Comment: I actually don't know your backend, so this is a hard question. Maybe you can paste some sample Json here

Comment: Am using parse and the ticket table have the pointer of address and company

Comment: I got the answer, use parse include method and refer the pointer col name